# HDMI not being read

Tags: 18.04, display, hdmi

I had HDMI working few days ago. Just today HDMI failed on me and I am completely oblivious to what to do. I have tried several things but didn't try everything. Both the Screen and the HDMI cable are 100% fine as they work on other devices. Any idea what should I do next? (Ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: Have you tried pluging in and out when both the tv and pc are on? Have you tried logging off and on with the cable plugged in? Do you have the right channel on on the tv.

Comment: I have both plugged on, Logged off and restarted with the cable plugged in, And yes I have the right channel because the TV reads that there is something connected but not vice versa.